# What happened to the blink/flash animation when taking a screenshot with Windows + PrintScreen on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

Back in Windows 8/8.1, whenever I used the Windows Key + PrintScreen keyboard shortcut to take a screenshot, there would be a quick blink/flash animation to indicate that I had taken a screenshot.

However, after upgrading to Windows 10, I find that the blink/flash no longer happens when I do Windows + PrintScreen, even though the keyboard shortcut actually does take screenshots successfully.

Does anybody know what happened to the screenshot animation in Windows 10/is there a way to enable it if the option is disabled and hidden somewhere?

I find it really useful to know if the computer actually registered the fact that I've pressed the Windows and Printscreen buttons considering that my keyboard is not too good at registering all button presses, especially for rarely used buttons like PrintScreen.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple system setting that is changed. You can follow this step and you'll get the animation of taken screenshot.

- From the Start Screen, swipe from right and click Search.
- Type **Performance**
- Select the option **“Adjust the appearance of performance of Windows”**
- If **“Custom”** is selected, please verify that the second option **“Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing”** is checked.
- Select Apply and the OK.

***Note: If the box is already checked, please uncheck it, apply, check it again and apply*.**

It's a solution given by microsoft forums
[Screen doesn't blink any more when capture screenshot](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro3/screen-doesnt-blink-any-more-when-using-windows/34ea522e-1d16-45cd-af1f-ababe61f089a)

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried it, and it still has an animation when you press `Windows + PrntScr`. It makes a small fade for a second, and the screenshot appears in `Pictures\Screenshots`.

Check if the screenshots are being saved, because if not, there might be a problem with your keyboard.

Comment: The screenshots are indeed being saved to Pictures\Screenshots. Do you suppose it's a problem with the computer? I'm running on a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I just found this link since I was having the same problem after the Windows 10 Creators Update Vesion 1703 even though it says Windows 8, 8.1 it still works for Windows 10. Side note if you already have the box checked that's in the link I left below then uncheck it then recheck it then hit apply & now when you use the Windows button plus PrnScr you will see a flash it worked out for me. Here's the link.
https://winaero.com/blog/fix-the-screen-does-not-dim-when-you-take-a-screenshot-using-winprintscreen-in-windows-8-1-or-windows-8/